# Using a .bat file, I need to extract information after ")" punctuation from a variable and store it in another variable?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have a variable from a text file.
     set /p namz=<"playersname.txt"
Right now if I echoed this, it would echo the entire contents of the file.
The Contents of playersname.txt include the following,
     theplayernameis:Player One
I need a code that I can use in .bat to help me to extract everything after the ":" from the .txt file while ignoring everything else before it, "Player One" then it needs to store it in another variable which I can call upon anytime I want it.
I've been racking my brain on this, trying to come up with a solution, been forum hopping for a long time, haven't quite found what I needed yet. Please help..

Comment: You have to show us the sample content of your text file.

Comment: playersname.txt = theplayernameis:Player One

Comment: It's a single lined text file, that is the contents I just need a way to extract everything after a certain symbol or letter from the text file. In example, the symbol would be, ":"

Comment: `echo %namz:*:=%` or store it in another variable: `set zman=%namz:*:=%`.

Comment: @JosefZ I was looking, I have another file instead of ":" separating the name from the variable to be It's, "\" How would I edit the code? answer this and you'll get chosen as best answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single-line textfile, you need the second token after a delimiter that might be `:` or `/`:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:/" %%a in (playersname.txt) do set namz=%%a
```

add every possible delimter to `delims=`

Comment: Worked Great, Thanks. @Stephan